# how to convert two dimensional array of chars to char**?

Tags: arrays, char

I have a print func like below:

```
void print(char **p)
{
    cout<<p[0]<<endl;
}
```

Here is my main func

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char a[50][50];
    strcpy(a[0], "hello");
    print(&a[0]);
}
```

The print func call will get compilation error. My question is without modifying the definition of the print func, how do I modify the print func call to make it print out hello?

Update: following code would work.

```
char *temp=a[0];
print(&temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you tont need to convert anyting. If you call a funktion with an Array as a parameter, this is always a pointer. At my point of view you just have to call

print(a[0]);

What you did would cause a char *** as parameter.

Comment: tried that, you will get compilation error, cannot convert parameter1 from char[50] to char **.

Comment: right, if you do this u have to change to this: void print(char *p)
if you realy want to vertage the 2D array it seames you have to cast it like this: print((char ** )a);
I dont realy unterstand why ...